# XML drawables not showing up on actual devices

Tags: android, xml, shapes, xml-drawable

This is not like other questions asked, so try to understand my problem.
I have

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="ring" >

<size
    android:height="30dp"
    android:width="30dp" />

<solid android:color="#009688" />
```

and I have my TextView as follows

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.bradley.learndrawable.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/test"
    android:text="2"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

It should display the text view as a circle with green color, and a number with white color.
It is doing fine on the Graphical View but not on the actual device.

I have copied the drawable to every drawable folder.
Still no good luck for me.

Help! :)

[Screenshot of Graphical View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEM6Q.jpg)

Comment: Is should just be in the drawable folder with nothing after that.

Comment: I use Eclipse brother ☺

Comment: What happens if you set the text color to black? Is the text visible?

Comment: Yes the text is visible, i tried that before also, but the background is not visible

Answer (score 0):

can you try `android:layerType="software"`. I am not sure if this will solve the problem but it could work

Comment: If you are not sure about the answer you can post it in the comments

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler ah thats smart I will definitely do that next time then. Thanks!